# Working with c# and byte[] serialization in multilanguage projects

Tags: c#, serialization

i'm trying to Create a Tool that convert a Excel sheets to a srialized .byte file to be read during runtime process of my other software.

actually i have something like this.

| index | col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index1 | text | text |
| index2 | text | text |
| index3 | text | text |

so i need to serialize custom format that encodes column information in a byte format, since this should be the faster in term of performance when i'm going to read out data.

anyone know a good way or a good reasources where i can look at?

Comment: Why binary serialization and not something interoperable like json?

Comment: @TheGeneral or BSON. Same newtonsoft

Comment: @T.S. or that too :) .

Comment: Then you need to serialize this data into a well-known format, like JSON or XML, or CSV. These formats are readable by all types of software, So you can always deserialize it

Comment: they are slower , that's because i'm not going in that way

Comment: You are not going in any "way" at the moment though. Anyway, i feel this question is a little open ended and broad for stackoverflow. Take a look at [ask] see if you can modify the question to include a finite problem domain, including what you have tried and what in particular you having trouble with... Good luck

Comment: "they are slower" - do you actually have a performance problem? yet? I can pretty much guarantee that serialization won't be your bottleneck!

Comment: hi TheGeneral, thank's you for your advice, as i wrote, binary is faster than json or xml and by using memory stream i should be able to create a good structure, but since i'm not familiar with database and storing data in byte[] i'm looking to get some advice, that's all

Comment: hi  Mitch Wheat than's you for your help, in serialization no.. but when are you going to read out data from json file and binary file there is...

Comment: "Binary" is not a specification. All computer data is binary. If you're talking about inventing a custom format that encodes column information in a byte format you design...don't do that (you'll have to invent a method of deserializing it in every application that wants to use it, instead of using a well supported library). If you're talking about using .net binary serialisation...also don't do that (not all applications are written in .net). Just use a well-known serialisation format instead of making the job difficult.

Comment: yes, custom format that encodes column information in a byte format is what i'm looking for, because from what know is faster than json file.. or i'm wrong?

Comment: after some researches i'm going to use BSON, than's to all for your advice